# Playback 24bit audio not possible

Tags: windows-xp, audio, autohotkey, codec, mci

I'm trying to play a 24bit audio file with my AutoHotkey app. It just uses [SoundPlay](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SoundPlay.htm). Windows 7 has no problem, however Windows XP users cannot play the 24bit files.

The [documentation](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SoundPlay.htm) says:

> All Windows OSes should be able to
>   play .wav files. However, other files
>   (.mp3, .avi, etc.) might not be
>   playable if the right codecs or
>   features aren't installed on the OS.

Possible fixes mentioned in the article [How to play 24bit WAV files in Windows Media Player](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jongallant/archive/2007/05/23/how-to-play-24-bit-wav-files-in-windows-media-player-media-encoder.aspx?PageIndex=2#comments) are fixing the problem for Windows Media Player, however but not for autohotkey:

**Step-by-step guide**

1. Download [Legacy HD Audio Filter](http://chrisnet.net/code.htm)
2. regsvr32.exe AudioTypeConvert.ax
3. Play 24bit file in windows media player (works) and AHK (no sound).
4. regsvr32.exe /u AudioTypeConvert.ax to uninstall

Expected behaviour: audio file playsback without errors in both Windows Media Player and AutoHotkey Apps.
Actual behavious: audio file playsback without errors only in Windows Media Player and does not playback in AutoHotkey Apps under Windows XP.

**Further Investigation**

As mentioned in the AutoHotKey forums SoundPlay is using [mciSendString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709492%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) under the hood and more information on the nature of the error can be gained by calling it directly.

Using the mciSendString alternative DLL call I get [error message 320](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa228215%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) which corresponds to [MCIERR_WAVE_OUTPUTSINUSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713501%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> All waveform devices that can play files in the current format are in use. Wait until one of these devices is free; then, try again.

How do I play 24bit audio files in Windows XP in my AutoHotkey app?

**SoundPlay based Test app** ([download](http://amasan.co.uk/downloads/bard/TestApp.ahk))

```
#NoEnv 
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
FileSelectFile, f
SoundPlay, %f%
Msgbox, You should hear audio - except for 24bit wave files under Windows XP.
```

**MCI based test app** ([download](http://amasan.co.uk/downloads/bard/TestApp2.ahk))

```
#NoEnv 
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
FileSelectFile, f
TryPlaySound(f)
Msgbox, You should hear audio - except for 24bit wave files under Windows XP.

; If SoundPlay does not work TryPlaySound
TryPlaySound( mFile ) 
{ 
    ; SKAN  www.autohotkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=361791#361791
    VarSetCapacity( DN,16 ), DLLFunc := "winmm.dll\mciSendString" ( A_IsUnicode ? "W" : "A" )
    DN := DllCall(DLLFunc, Str, "play " """" mFile """" "", Uint, 0, Uint, 0, Uint, 0)
    Return DN
}
```

Comment: Ideas to improve the question itself are happily accepted in comments.

Comment: How to improve something that is so perfect. +1 for the details provided in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would convert the 24-bit file to a 16-bit file, if that's at all feasible.

Comment: In this case I don't have any control over the files. I guess the only solution is to call a thirdparty DLL like Bass to do the playback.

Comment: If it were me, I'd check the file header for 24-bitness and make a temporary 16-bit copy and play that before I'd pull in another DLL, but I'm old school.